# How to add vertical menu PHP

Tags: php, html, css, menu

```
 <ul id="verticalmenu">
   <li><a href="http://www.yourlink.com/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.yourlink.com/">Vertical Menu</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://www.yourlink.com/">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.yourlink.com/">Fading Banner</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.yourlink.com/">Web Design Blog</a></li>  
</ul>
```

If this is my menu.php, how can I call it on other pages? I want it to be static or say fixed.
It should be present in every page, I navigate to.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2j0nq5i.jpg

How can I do so, just like the red block in the img??

Comment: `include("menu.php")` on every page wherever you want it.

Comment: but will it appear to left left side?? after the header??

Comment: if you include it after the header and the style says put it on the left (which by default it should be left aligned.

Comment: What if I have to place it on the right side?? how can I do that?

Comment: You should be including this on your page and using css to style the html block however/wherever you want it.

Comment: can you please tell me the syntax? and where should i use it?

Comment: Probably not without at least seeing your html source and most likely after that re-writing it to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a `header.php` file that contains the full header of your site, including the menu. Once you have done that, you can just call `include("header.php");` on every page and your entire header will be brought in. This will also allow you to make one change in one file and affect the entire site.

To position the menu on the left or right, you are going to want to wrap the menu with a css call similar to `float: left;` or `float: right;` jsfiddlee: http://jsfiddle.net/jjS98/

here is the css code for floating your menu to the right:

```
#verticalmenu{
    float:right;
}
```

You can change right to left for the desired results.

Comment: Added example css code to float your menu right/left